# Filter Flutter listview.builder by category from Firestore

Tags: flutter, filtering

I'm trying to filter my list by category, but no success so far. I've tried several ways to implemet it and also asked some friends. Unfortunately non of their answers has worked yet.

This is the full code for the screen. I´d like to be able to filter documents by category, something like: "Where()"...

Any idea?

Thanks.

```html
class ListGameWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ListGameWidget(this._gameList, this._title);

  final List<Game> _gameList;
  final String _title;

  @override
  _ListGameWidgetState createState() => _ListGameWidgetState();
}

class _ListGameWidgetState extends State<ListGameWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: widget._gameList != null && widget._gameList.isNotEmpty
              ? Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      widget._title,
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: widget._gameList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            var game = widget._gameList[index];
                            return Card(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                      child: Image(
                                        image: NetworkImage(widget._gameList
                                            .elementAt(index)
                                            .imagen1),
                                        height: 100.0,
                                        width: 133.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        game.tienda,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      Text(game.tipo),
                                      Text(game.comunidad),
                                      Text(game.tel1, style: TextStyle()),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to filter by? You only have one list.

Comment: Thank you! This is a list of shops, so I want to filter them by categories (restaurants, bakeries...)

Comment: I don't know how you load you data, but perhaps the best way is to load the filtered data from Firestore.

Comment: Could be. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should refill your dataSet in _gameList and setState. For Example:
-Create a button for alphabetical order for shops
-Reorganize dataset and fill _gameList in onTap event.

Comment: Thank you. How to show the elements from a specific category when the screen loads?

Comment: You can use initState for preloading data before screen loads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a category first, it's missing in your code.
You use the category to create a list from the original list:

```
String category="id of category";
List filtered = originalList.where((e)=>e.categoryId == category).toList();

In listview use the filtered list to build your elements.
```

But still, you code is lacking many details.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I did input the full code.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are serious or trolling. Share your model, and share what you want to filter by. All the code you posted only shows a listview builder.